# Setting --data-binary using libcurl in c++

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I'm using the curl api from `http://curl.haxx.se/` in a c++ application. I'm trying to write the equivalent of:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-16" --data-binary @some data.json
```

I'm using `curl_easy_setopt()` to set up the various options but the bit I can't figure out is the `--data-binary` flag. Which `CURLOPT` setting would I use to set this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> specify data to `POST` to server [...] Pass a `char *` as parameter, pointing to the full data to send in a `HTTP POST` operation. You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it.

Note: you can easily discover this by using the `--libcurl` option:

```
--libcurl FILE  Dump libcurl equivalent code of this command line
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` but the buffer I want to pass is a `wchar_t*` not a `char*`. Would this make any difference?

I was specifically interested in explicitly stating that the data was binary like the `-binary` in the command line from my original question.

Comment: libcurl expects a byte array so you need to convert your sequence of wide characters into a multibyte string e.g with [wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/) and use the [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.html) option so that to pass explicitly the length of the multibyte string (as returned by `wcstombs`).